# Best way to map Text and Image while loading the data

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a csv file which looks somewhat like in the photo.

[image: CSV file]

I'm building a model that takes both image and its corresponding text (`df['Content']` as input .

I wanted to know the best way to load this data in the following way:

- Loading the images from `df['Image_location']` into a tensor.
- And preserving the order of the image to the corresponding text.
- Preserving the corresponding label (`df['Sentiment']`)

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

Create dummy data:

```py
import numpy
from PIL import Image

for i in range(1, 3):
  imarray = numpy.random.rand(64,64,3) * 255
  im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8')).convert('RGBA')
  im.save('result_image{}.png'.format(i))
```

Process:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'Location': ['some.txt', 'some-other.txt'], 
                         'Content': ['This road was ok', 'This was wonderful'],
                         'Score': [0.0353, -0.341],
                         'Sentiment': ['Neutral', 'Positive'],
                         'Image_location': ['/content/result_image1.png', '/content/result_image2.png']})

features = df[['Content', 'Image_location']]
labels = df['Sentiment']

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
def process_path(x):
  content, image_path = x[0], x[1]
  img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=3)
  return content, img

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (process_path(x), y))

for x, y in dataset.take(1):
  content = x[0]
  image = x[1]
  print('Content -->', content)
  print('Sentiment -->', y)
  plt.imshow(image.numpy())
```

```
Content --> tf.Tensor(b'This road was ok', shape=(), dtype=string)
Sentiment --> tf.Tensor(b'Neutral', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, this works absolutely fine. Thanks

Comment: just a follow up @AloneTogether , is it possible to batch this dataset?

Comment: coz while unpacking in the for loop, I'm facing issues.

Comment: Yes batching should not be a problem with dataset.batch()

Comment: actually when I batch and unpack the dataset, an error comes. I did dataset.batch(32) and I'm getting this error on line `for step , (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):` . The error is ` InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [344,500,3], [batch]: [500,333,3] [Op:IteratorGetNext] `

Comment: Have you tried dataset.batch(32, drop_remainder=True)

Comment: yup, same error. By looking at the error, don't you think if there is a problem in dimensionality (axis) ?

Comment: It is unfortunately hard to say, I just tried using a batch size in my example and it works just fine.